# TYPO3 own tt_content colpos columns

Tags: php, typo3

I have TYPO3 version 6.2.4.

I want to rename columns in backend from `left`, `normal`, `right` and `border` to `main`, `microsite` and `mobile`

I added into `extTables.php`

```
$TCA["tt_content"]["columns"]["colPos"]["config"]["items"] = array (
    "0" => array ("Main||Main||||||||","0"),
    "1" => array ("Mobile||Mobile||||||||","1"),
    "2" => array ("MicroSite||MicroSite||||||||","2"),
);
```

I deleted all the cache by button in backend and I also deleted temp folder manually.

I can see the right names in **configuration** in TYPO3 backend but when I open **page** there are still the old names.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TYPO3 6.0+ you can use with easy `Backend Layout` record for this, just create it in your storage folder use the visual editor and later choose new layout in page's properties, **Appearance > Backend Layout (this page only)** and **Backend Layout (subpages of this page)**

sample config of what you want looks like:

```
backend_layout {
    colCount = 1
    rowCount = 3
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Main
                    colPos = 0
                }
            }
        }
        2 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = Mobile
                    colPos = 1
                }
            }
        }
        3 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = MicroSite
                    colPos = 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```